# I want to categorize column based on condition

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

I have two column as below:

| I | J |
| --- | --- |
| 0.7525801225 | 29.04 |
| 0.7413918015 | 31.19 |
| 0.732754867 | 35.49 |
| 0.4659390421 | 51.62 |
| 0.3520797622 | 69.9 |
| 0.5917089747 | 40.87 |

I want to categorize based on following:
***A > 0.5 and B > 50 = A,
A > 0.5 and B < 50 = B,
A < 0.5 and B > 50 = C,
A < 0.5 and B < 50 = D***

I tried the following :

```
=IF(AND($C6>=0.5,$G6>=50%),"A",IF(AND($C6>=0.5,$G6<50%),"B",IF(AND($C6<0.5,$G6>=50%),"C",IF(AND($C6<0.5,$G6<50%),"D"))))
```

But its only returning **A** and **C**

Comment: **ALL** of your values in **J** are `> 50%`, so that is what I would expect.

Comment: Hi @Maqsud Inamdar,, nothing wrong with your formula simple rewrite data in `Col J` should written like `29.40%` since you are testing data in Percentage form !! And to get Category `A` both `C6 & G6` must have `>=0.5 and >=50%`.